# How to remove default divider from recylerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have added android-recyclerview in my app which is running fine. According to my layout i have to remove divider between cells. In list view this can easily be achieved by setting divider property to null like below in code but i am not able to find any such property in android-recyclerview. How can i achieve this in android-recyclerview.

```
getListView().setDivider(null);
getListView().setDividerHeight(0);
     OR
android:divider="@null"
android:dividerHeight="0dp"
```

Recylerview xml below :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recycler_view_contact_list_frag"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.8"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:scrollbars="vertical" />
```

Adapter xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/recyclerview_item_borders"
android:padding="10dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/section_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:paddingBottom="30dp"
    >


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview_section_header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >
    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/circular_image_contact"
      android:layout_width="@dimen/auto_complete_circular_image_dimen"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/auto_complete_circular_image_dimen"
        app:civ_border_color="#FF000000"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_default_contact"
        app:civ_border_width="0dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.8"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_contact_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:textColor="@color/textDarkColor"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_contact_number"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:textColor="@color/textDarkColor"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />


    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Recyclerview has no dividers by default

Comment: set android:dividerHeight="0dp" in your xml file .

Comment: @SorathiyaPayal There are no dividers in Recylerview!!! please refer this link https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html

Comment: Thanks for your comments , i am talking about seperator/divider between cells. As u can see attach image above

Comment: Can you please share your adpater xml file

Comment: post your adapter xml

Answer (score 1):

Remove background from adapter

```
  android:background="@drawable/recyclerview_item_borders"
```

Answer (score 0):

Recyclerview don't have the divider by default. If you need to add the divider, you have to add the decoration to the recyclerview.

Answer (score 0):

It is from the custom view you are using by default there is no divider. share your code thn any one can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change it in the List item view. Add following parameters to list item view.

```
card_view:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
card_view:cardElevation="0dp" 
card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
```

In list_item_view.xml

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
  android:id="@+id/card_view"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_gravity="center"
  card_view:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
  card_view:cardElevation="0dp"
  card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">
```

Then set background color of your Recycle view to its foreground color. If it is white,

In recycle_view.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
  android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:background="#ffffff"
  android:scrollbars="vertical"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```